# Cannot convert value of type 'URLRequest' to expected argument type 'URL'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following code

```
  let request = createURLRequest(toEndpoint: endpoint, using: method, body: body)
  let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: request)
```

createURLRequest returns a URLRequest

I'm getting the following error on the line where URLSession.shared.data is called

```
Cannot convert value of type 'URLRequest' to expected argument type 'URL'
```

I need to pass in a URLRequest to URLSession.shared.data. How can I do that? I'm trying to convert my code to use async/await

Comment: Typo, replace `from:` with `for:`. Please use code completion (or have a look into the documentation of `URLSession`) to figure out the proper method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused between two methods below from URLSession:

> public func data(for request: URLRequest, delegate: (URLSessionTaskDelegate)? = nil) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse)

> public func data(from url: URL, delegate: (URLSessionTaskDelegate)? = nil) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse)

The correct one is `URLSession.shared.data(for: request)`